# Want to populate datatable row one by one using asynchronous in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am facing a problem where I want to return all the rows one by one without interupting the current function. The issue is intermittent. Sometimes I can get all the datatables data but sometimes not.

Then I started investigating and realised after checking the developer tool in network section that it throws error after page 10. And the error is `429 too many requests`. Also, realised that the script was synchronous json call.

> 429 too many requests

I tried using below code in my script but the spin is not working. Also, found that this is not recommended way.

Can someone help me with solution? Thank you

```
 // Set the global configs to synchronous 
            $.ajaxSetup({
                async: false
            });
```

My Script

```
function getMed(sDate, eDate) {
     var pData;    
    var firstURL = mUrl + "?sDate=" + moment(sDate).format(dateFormat) + "&eDate=" + moment(eDate).add(1, 'day').format(dateFormat) + "&pNum=1";
   ....
    }).done(function (data) {
       
        if (pData.Number > 0) {          
            var counter = 0;
           // Set the global configs to synchronous 
            $.ajaxSetup({
                async: false
            });

            var requestsProcessed = 0;
            for (var i = 1; i <= pData.Number; i++) {
                $("#iconSpin").css('display', 'block');   
                
                var pURL = mUrl + "?sDate=" + moment(sDate).format(dateFormat) + "&eDate=" + moment(eDate).add(1, 'day').format(dateFormat) + "&pNum=" + i;
                console.log("calling: " + pURL);
                var pageRequest = $.getJSON(pURL, function (data) {

                    requestsProcessed++;
                    $("#progress").innerHTML = "Fetching batch " + requestsProcessed + " of " + pData.Number + " batches.";
                   ....

                }).fail(function () {                   
                    $("#iconSpin").css('display', 'none');                   
                    console.log("fail for " + pURL + " in " + new Date());
                });
                console.log("completed for " + pURL + " in " + new Date());

            }
        } else {
            alert("There is no data.");
           
        }

    }).fail(function () {     
    
        $("#iconSpin").css('display', 'none');      
    });
}
```

Comment: "Also, found that this is not recommended way." So what about using the recommended way?

Comment: @Thomas, I do not what is the other way to use this. Also, `$("#iconSpin").css('display', 'block');` does not work.